# Outlook Out of Office Message

Tags: microsoft-outlook

An email recipient has an out of office message created.  However, when hovering over the message in order to view full content, the message is cut off on the right side of the screen.  Is there a way to view the recipients out of office message in its entirety?

Comment: Send that mail you’re composing?

Comment: If you talk about the preview then it's normal. You get the full message once you send the mail to that person.

Answer (score 1):

This is by design that Outlook may only show part of OOF if the content is too long.

[image]

This is just a notification to let you know that user is OOF. Either follow Daniel's suggestion to send out the email or submit a feedback to [Outlook UserVoice forum](https://outlook.uservoice.com/forums/322590-outlook-2016-for-windows).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but since this is still how Outlook behaves and others might want to know, this is handy...

If you have Microsoft Teams, hover over the contact there, will show you the message in its entirety. Still not formatted, though, but complete.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHnd8.png)